# Get installed apps as APK within Android?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, apk

I'm looking for an application that will let me easily export any application I have to APK format (I'm not rooted). Normally, AirDroid does this easily and I love AirDroid for that. However, one of the downsides was that I need to be around a computer to do the said process. Are there any apps that offer a way for me to output the APK file from within the Android itself? I can see that some backup solutions provide this but I don't want a whole new backup system just to do this one small task. A small utility app of sorts would be really nice which has only one purpose and that is to produce the APK file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup apps using [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro).

Alternatively, you can use a little app dedicated for this task: [App Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup).

Comment: Yup, that's what I needed! Thanks! Shame it can't backup system apps too though.