# how to capture any .apk download

Tags: google-play-store, apk

We are seeking a reliable method to get the .apk file for any arbitrary application that may currently exist on Google Play store. ("legit" reasons may be e.g. to later restore to *application v8* even if only *application v11* is available to public).

I am not aware of any utility that can do this, so one approach might be to capture all packets which cross your wireless network to your Android device, like when the user installs an app from Play store. So we want to see if it's possible to capture all .apk files downloaded to the Android device upon user install from Play.

1. which wireless capture utility should you use (e.g. [pcap](http://www.kismetwireless.net/android-pcap/)?), and should it be run from your Android or some other machine?
2. how do you reassemble a .apk file from a sequence of frames?
3. Is there any encryption of data that would prevent the capture of the .apk file?
4. Is there an easier way to get an .apk? Tried the [emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) but it doesn't work for all apps. `adb backup` gives a compressed `.ab` file, but we want the `.apk` itself in extracted form, and not buried in some `.ab` compressed file.

Comment: Related: [Can I build an APK from an installed app and its data?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28116)

Comment: Related: [How to access Android APKs without rooting](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27780)

Comment: Related: [Get installed apps as APK within Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24277)

Comment: Related: [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12330)

Comment: As for your "legit" reason: [Where can find older versions of Apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14910)

Answer (score 1):

Why so difficult? Simply install [AppMonster Pro Backup Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.think_android.appmanagerpro) (yes, the Pro version -- the free doesn't do this automatically), and on each install/update the corresponding `.apk` file is automatically backed up to your SDCard. You can configure the app to keep all `.apk` files, or only the latest N (number freely configurable), even pinning of a "stable version" to always keep is possible.

[image: AppMonster Pro settings] [image: AppMonster Pro main screen]

*AppMonster* only takes care for the `.apk` files (not for app data). As a side effect, it even shows you if an app contains an ad module, and you can have it notify you if an just installed app can be moved to SDCard via App2SD.

Comment: +1 although the answer at http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27783/23748 worked for me (free).

Comment: If you are satisfied with doing so manually, you can of course also take the free version of AppMonster. I understood you wanted to do so automatically on each install/update. Nevermind: Now you've got a choice :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched previous questions? I think that both [How to take backup of all installed APKs from Phone to PC](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20606/11343) and [How to access Android APKs without rooting](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/27780/11343) answer this question by providing utilities to extract/backup the APK files for installed apps. Do none of those suggestions suit your goal?

IMHO trying to sniff and reassemble packets is much too complicated - I recommend continued investigation into on-device utilities.